# Can you split a two-column article into further columns?

Tags: tables, two-column, multicolumn

I enjoy writing my math notes/lectures like so:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn, 10px]{article}
```

Before I discovered the code above I was using the package paracol to split the page whenever I want, but my professor recently started writing equations next to tabular environments. My question is there an easy way to write equations side-by-side either to the left or right of a tabular environment when already in a two-column format. For example If I wanted equations in that blue circle but still remaining in the left column:

[image]

Though I doubt you guys need the code for such a simple tabular I provided it just in case :)

```
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
 $x$ & $f(x)$ \\
   \hline
 $0$ & $1-p$ \\
 $1$ & $p$
 \end{tabular}
```

Edit: Further testing I realized If I add the code to the end tabular line it does produce an equation to the right and centered relative to the tabular

```
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
 $x$ & $f(x)$ \\
   \hline
 $0$ & $1-p$ \\
 $1$ & $p$
 \end{tabular} $f(x)=p^x(1-p)^{1-x}\enspace x=0,1$
```

[image]

But I Suppose this would work only If I needed one equation, But if I needed a couple or maybe a cases environment I am not sure this method would work.

Comment: `multicol` package?

Comment: Ill try messing around with it!

Comment: @NotAZoomedImage: Combining the `multicol` package with a `twocolumn` documentclass, results in the following warning: "Package multicol Warning: May not work with the twocolumn option"

Comment: @leandriis: A very good info. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a suggestion:  You can lose the equation number using align*.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn, 10pt]{article}% 10px is not supported, and would be incredibly tiny
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  \begin{array}{c|c}
     x & f(x) \\
     \hline
     0 & 1-p \\
     1 & p
  \end{array} && % every second & separates an equation
  f(x)=p^x(1-p)^{1-x}\quad x=0,1
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative suggestion using two minipages:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for dummy text. Do not use in actual document.
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{minipage}{0.25\linewidth}
  \[\begin{array}{c|c}
     x & f(x) \\
     \hline
     0 & 1-p \\
     1 & p
  \end{array}\]
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.75\linewidth}
  \[f(x)=p^x(1-p)^{1-x}\quad x=0,1\]
\end{minipage}

\lipsum
\end{document}
```